# Nixos configuration use pinned nixpkgs for specific package

Tags: nixos, nix

So my `nixos-rebuild` fails to build due to the recent error of: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/74916

I thought I'd give a go at trying to fix this, by referencing a previous commit's package

I added the following in my config (under one of the let statements):

```
  nixpkgsMyStable = import (builtins.fetchTarball {
    url = https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/775fb69ed73e7cf6b7d3dd9853a60f40e8efc340.tar.gz;
    sha256 = "1w068b0ydw4c26mcjiwlzdfqcdk3rrwmfx4hxzgfhfwcz2nmh3if";
  }) {};
```

I then  replaced:

```
  boot.kernelPackages = pkgs.linuxPackages_latest;
```

with

```
  boot.kernelPackages = nixpkgsMyStable.pkgs.linuxPackages_latest;
```

However this fails with:

```
sudo nixos-rebuild switch
building Nix...
building the system configuration...
error: assertion failed at /nix/store/0272yl38a4mc20i2a5078m85bldipbjm-source/pkgs/os-specific/linux/prl-tools/default.nix:9:1
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
```

Is this possibly something to do with the newest kernel version? Or something I'm doing wrong in the above config?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/a7f58b42047255ef5c910450a9d92752a00773ff/pkgs/os-specific/linux/prl-tools/default.nix#L9) where the assertion fails, newer kernels are not supported by prl-tools:

> ```
> # Disable for kernels 4.15 and above due to compatibility issues
> assert kernel != null -> stdenv.lib.versionOlder kernel.version "4.15";
> ```

So Parallels is probably not compatible with latest kernel.